# ¿Cómo hacer extracción de tweets con R?

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando en un TFM y estoy usando (y aprendiendo R), estoy haciendo una extracción aleatoria de tweets de distinto periódicos nacionales para después tokenizarlos y poder introducirlos en la herramienta Gephy de análisis de redes, la parte de R que empleo es únicamente para la extracción, para la tokenización empleo python, el código en R que he desarrollado es el siguiente

```
library(twitteR)


api_key="JRG6DOruwiHo7PHAem73olJrx"
api_secret="CQH5vjiRwUa6QjU2KOVIasghwSRAv5fp6OkJfcS7F0pqXbmcdy"
access_token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_token_secret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)


cuentas<-c("elmundoes","el_pais","abc_es","larazon_es","eldiarioes","publico_es","okdiario",
           "LaUltima_Hora","LaVanguardia","libertaddigital","elconfidencial","elperiodico",
           "El_Plural","elespanolcom","20m","ElHuffPost","ESdiario_com","voz_populi","elindepcom",
           "_infoLibre","ElSaltoDiario","MediterraneoDGT","europapress")

df<-data.frame()

for(cuenta in cuentas){
  tweets<-twLisToDF(userTimeline(cuenta,n=3200,includeRts = T))
  df<-rbind(df,tweets)
  print(paste("Tweets sustraidos: ",cuenta))
}

prensa_df=df
save(df,file="prensa_df.RData")

replies_df<-prensa_df[complete.cases(prensa_df[,"replyToSN"]),]
rtweets_df<-prensa_df[prensa_df$isRetweet=="TRUE",]
tweets_df<-prensa_df[!complete.cases(prensa_df[,"replyToSN"])&prensa_df$isRetweet=="FALSE",]

write.csv(replies_df,"prensa_replies.CSV")
write.csv(rtweets_df,"prensa_rtweets.CSV")
write.csv(tweets_df,"prensa_tweets.csv")
```

Y los resultados de error que me da son los siguientes

```
library(twitteR)
  

api_key="JRG6DOruwiHo7PHAem73olJrx"
api_secret="CQH5vjiRwUa6QjU2KOVIasghwSRAv5fp6OkJfcS7F0pqXbmcdy"
access_token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_token_secret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
"Using direct authentication"


cuentas<-c("elmundoes","el_pais","abc_es","larazon_es","eldiarioes","publico_es","okdiario",
            "LaUltima_Hora","LaVanguardia","libertaddigital","elconfidencial","elperiodico",
            "El_Plural","elespanolcom","20m","ElHuffPost","ESdiario_com","voz_populi","elindepcom",
            "_infoLibre","ElSaltoDiario","MediterraneoDGT","europapress")

df<-data.frame()

for(cuenta in cuentas){
    tweets<-twLisToDF(userTimeline(cuenta,n=3200,includeRts = T))
    df<-rbind(df,tweets)
    print(paste("Tweets sustraidos: ",cuenta))
}
Error in twLisToDF(userTimeline(cuenta, n = 3200, includeRts = T)) : 
  could not find function "twLisToDF"

prensa_df=df
save(df,file="prensa_df.RData")

replies_df<-prensa_df[complete.cases(prensa_df[,"replyToSN"]),]
Error in `[.data.frame`(prensa_df, , "replyToSN") : 
  undefined columns selected
rtweets_df<-prensa_df[prensa_df$isRetweet=="TRUE",]
tweets_df<-prensa_df[!complete.cases(prensa_df[,"replyToSN"])&prensa_df$isRetweet=="FALSE",]
Error in `[.data.frame`(prensa_df, , "replyToSN") : 
  undefined columns selected

write.csv(replies_df,"prensa_replies.CSV")
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'replies_df' not found
write.csv(rtweets_df,"prensa_rtweets.CSV")
write.csv(tweets_df,"prensa_tweets.csv")
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'tweets_df' not found
```

si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podría haber más problemas, pero uno obvio es que en el primer bucle llamas a la función `twListToDF` como `twLisToDF`, falta una t antes de `To`. Por eso el error

```
 could not find function "twLisToDF"
```

Ese nombre no existe. Los demás errores creo que dependen de ese, al no tener lo que esperan en `prensa_df` generan errores porque no aparecen las columnas esperadas y cosas por el estilo.

A modo de sugerencia y sin prisas si es que estás aprendiendo. Si bien en `R` se puede trabajar con bucles y en algunos casos son la mejor opción, el lenguaje está más orientado a manipular listas usando iteradores como `lapply()` e ir creando objetos paso a paso. Personalmente esa aproximación se me hace mucho más sencilla que usar bucles, sobre todo para rastrear errores en el código.

Sugerencia 2: si te interesara hacer la tokenización directo en `R` hay una librería que se llama que es un poco lenta pero muy simple de trabajar. Lo mejor que tiene es está documentada en el libro https://www.tidytextmining.com/ , que es una entrada muy tersa al tema. Lamentablemente no está traducido al español.